# Firefox prints first page only but other browsers doing fine

Tags: firefox, printing

Print Preview of latest version of Firefox(in windows) shows something like this:

[image: Print Preview in Firefox]

There should be two pages but it only show first page. Logo of 2nd page is cut off as you can see.
What might be causes of this?

Comment: What would be the expected behaviour?

Comment: two pages with logo in each.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are using

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firefox previous versions had problem to print with long tables and iframes including absolute positioned elements.

If you don't see those elements,I suggest you to inspect such element with `display:table` or `display:flex` and without hesitation change it to `display:block` only for @media print

Another headache might be coming from overflow property. Find such element with `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:hidden` and of course write `overflow:visible` for @media print.

Thats all from me.

Comment: i spend almost two days on this, finally changing display to block worked. I can't explain how happy i'm now. Thank you so much. thank you stack overflow team.

Comment: I had to remove both `display:flex` and `display:-webkit-box`.

Comment: Flexbox was causing issues with Firefox Dev for me too! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Firefox printing only the first page.

In my case it turned out that

```
float: right;
```

was the problem. Firefox printed blank second page when float was set.

To fix it i had to use this code in CSS (eg. ):

```
@media print {
  div.example {
      float:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Had same problem using boostrap3 with a table inside a <div class="col-...">. Thanks for the float:none; tip!

Answer (score 0):

Here I configured the CSS files to become loaded only on the screen and the problem was solved.

```
<link href="../css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, the thing is bootstrap was adding `break-inside: avoid` to `<tr>`. 
So I added `table { tr { break-inside: auto }` which fixed issue on my part.
[image]